# Adjusting the HelixToolKit model's appearance

Tags: wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to show 3D view in one of my projects. I have a device and want to adjust its appearance based on data coming from the device. (Like Left, Right, Front)

Probably an easy place but I couldn't find it. How can I adjust the look of the model?

To be more explanatory; View adjustment can be made with clicks such as L, F, R from the ViewCube located in the lower right corner. How and where are these adjustments triggered? How can I access these settings?

Setting it up with the C # code I need.

[image]

C# Code

```
        //Path to the model file
    private const string MODEL_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\dice.stl";
    SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ModelVisual3D device3D = new ModelVisual3D();
        device3D.Content = Display3d(MODEL_PATH);
        // Add to view port
        viewPort3d.Children.Add(device3D);

        var axis = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
        var angle = 50;

        var matrix = device3D.Transform.Value;
        matrix.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis, angle));

        device3D.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(matrix);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display 3D Model
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">Path to the Model file</param>
    /// <returns>3D Model Content</returns>
    private Model3D Display3d(string model)
    {
        Model3D device = null;
        try
        {
            //Adding a gesture here
            viewPort3d.RotateGesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);

            //Import 3D model file
            ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();

            //Load the 3D model file
            device = import.Load(model);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception in case can not file 3D model
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Error : " + e.StackTrace);
        }
        return device;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old now, but...
If I understand, you want to change the position of the camera.

Below is an example of how to force camera properties in a HelixViewport3D.

Tip: You can use HelixViewport3D's ShowCameraInfo="True" to test the camera coordinates.

```
<hx:HelixViewport3D x:Name="MyViewport" ShowCameraInfo="True">
     <hx:DefaultLights/>
     <hx:CubeVisual3D/>
</hx:HelixViewport3D>


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyViewport.CameraController.CameraLookDirection = new Vector3D(0, -4.7, 0);
    MyViewport.CameraController.CameraPosition = new Point3D(0, 4.7, 0);
    MyViewport.CameraController.CameraTarget = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
    MyViewport.CameraController.CameraUpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
}
```